Reproduction of graphics issues: cyclic overlap and close parametrization
I was trying to reproduce the graphics below (reference):

Here is what I tried:
1. Invent a model for radius parametrization:
ClearAll[modu];
modu[t_]:=.1+.5Abs[Sin[Pi Mod[t,1]^4]]^.5
Plot[modu[3t],{t,0,1},PlotRange->{0,1}]


2. Construct the final visual:
ciRnuM=200;
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[.7],White]],FaceForm[Black],
MapIndexed[Disk[#1,modu[3#2[[1]]/ciRnuM]]&,Reverse@CirclePoints[ciRnuM]]},
Background->Black]


As you can see this is pretty bad. There are 2 key issues:

Disks are not overlapping cyclically
The shape of radius parametrization is far from original


Could you suggest how to fix these?


Add the code by @A.Kato in the comment.
Clear["Global`*"];
rot[t_] := 0.19*(1 - 0.3*Sin[3 t])^4;
disks = Table[p = AngleVector[t];
   center = RotationMatrix[-rot[t]] . p;
   radius = 2 Sin[rot[t]/2]; 
   Disk[center, radius], {t, Reverse[2. Pi*Subdivide[120]]}];

interval = 2;
Graphics[{FaceForm[Black], EdgeForm[White], 
  RegionDifference[First@#, RegionUnion[Rest@#]] & /@ 
   Most@Partition[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics /@ disks, interval, 1, 
     1]}] 


Edit

We use Partition[...,interval,1,1]  with interval=20 to get the cyclic partitions and then use RegionDifference for such partitions.

We still need to find the suitable function modu[t].


Clear["Global`*"];
modu[t_] := .1 + .5 Abs[Sin[Pi Mod[t, 1]^4]]^.5
ciRnuM = 200;
interval = 20;
disks = MapIndexed[Disk[#1, modu[3 #2[[1]]/ciRnuM]] &, 
   Reverse@CirclePoints[ciRnuM]];
g1=Graphics[{FaceForm[Black], EdgeForm[White], 
  RegionDifference[First@#, RegionUnion[Rest@#]] & /@ 
   Partition[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics /@ disks, interval, 1, 1]}];
g2=Graphics[{FaceForm[RandomColor[]], 
    EdgeForm[
     White], #} & /@ (RegionDifference[First@#, 
      RegionUnion[Rest@#]] & /@ 
    Partition[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics /@ disks, interval, 1, 1]), 
 Background -> Black];
GraphicsRow[{g1,g2}]



test another function f[t].

Clear["Global`*"];
f[t_] := 0.3 + .2*Sin[2 π*t*3];
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
disks = Table[
   Disk[{Cos[2 π*t], Sin[2 π*t]}, f[t]], {t, 1, 0, -.01}];
interval = 10;
Graphics[{FaceForm[Black], EdgeForm[White], 
  RegionDifference[First@#, RegionUnion[Rest@#]] & /@ 
   Most@Partition[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics /@ disks, interval, 1, 
     1]}]


Original

A starting point since we need to construct a suitable functions to make the original pictures.
To make overlapping cyclically,we use RegionDifference to difference between two adjacent disks.
compare with g1 and g2.

Clear["Global`*"];
disks = Table[
   BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@
    Disk[{Cos[2 π*t], 
      Sin[2 π*t]}, (0.2 + .1*Sin[2 π*t*6])], {t, 0, 1, .01}];
g1 = Graphics[{FaceForm[Black], EdgeForm[White], 
    RegionDifference /@ Partition[disks, 2, 1]}];
g2 = Graphics[{FaceForm[Black], EdgeForm[White], disks}];
GraphicsRow[{g1, g2}]



Sweet (+1) ! Neat trick with RegionDifference. If you ever guess / fund a similar parametrization used in original for radius -- please let me know.

Nice trick (+1)! Replacing your "disks" by following looks somewhat closer to the original:   rot[t_]:= 0.19*(1-0.3Sin[3t])^4;
disks=Table[p=AngleVector[t]; center=RotationMatrix[-rot[t]].p; radius=2Sin[rot[t]/2]; Disk[center, radius], {t,Reverse[2.PiSubdivide[120]]}];

@A.Kato Good viewpoint! You should add an answer to this question.

Thanks (^_^) But I don't intend to claim much originality in this parametrization. I would be happy if you could incorporate it into your code.

q = 10; p = 5; m = 3;
(* q=10;p=10;m=7; *)
Graphics[{Circle[], EdgeForm[White], FaceForm[Black], 
   Table[Disk[{Cos[
        1/2 ArcCos[
           1 - 8 (x Sin[\[Pi]/(2 p)])^2 + 
            8 (x Sin[\[Pi]/(2 p)])^4] + (i/q - 1) \[Pi]/p], 
       Sin[1/2 ArcCos[
           1 - 8 (x Sin[\[Pi]/(2 p)])^2 + 
            8 (x Sin[\[Pi]/(2 p)])^4] + (i/q - 1) \[Pi]/p]}, 
      x Sqrt[2 - Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 + Cos[(2 \[Pi])/p]]]] /. 
     x -> 0.5 + Sin[i*Pi/(p q)*m]/2.5, {i, 1, 2 p q}], Red, 
   Point[{1, 0}]}, PlotRange -> {{Automatic, 0}, Automatic}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{0.1, 0}, {0.1, 0.1}}, Background -> Black];
Graphics[{Circle[], EdgeForm[White], FaceForm[Black], 
   Table[Disk[{Cos[
        1/2 ArcCos[
           1 - 8 (x Sin[\[Pi]/(2 p)])^2 + 
            8 (x Sin[\[Pi]/(2 p)])^4] + ((i + p q)/q - 1) \[Pi]/p], 
       Sin[1/2 ArcCos[
           1 - 8 (x Sin[\[Pi]/(2 p)])^2 + 
            8 (x Sin[\[Pi]/(2 p)])^4] + ((i + p q)/q - 1) \[Pi]/p]}, 
      x Sqrt[2 - Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 + Cos[(2 \[Pi])/p]]]] /. 
     x -> 0.5 + Sin[(i + p q)*Pi/(p q)*m]/2.5, {i, 1, 2 p q}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, Automatic}, Automatic}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.1}}, Background -> Black];
GraphicsRow[{%%, %}, 0, Background -> Black, PlotRangePadding -> None]






(+1) Cool. How did you solve the overlap explained in simple terms ?

@VitaliyKaurov The final image consists of two half images - left one and right one. Left one is produced by plotting from angle 0 degrees so overlap occurs at 0 degrees but this part is not visible because only left half is taken. The right image is produced by plotting form angle 180 degrees so overlap occurs at 180 degrees but this part is not visible because only right half is taken.

A 3D version, using disks definition by @A.Kato in the comment.
rot[t_] := 0.19*(1 - 0.3*Sin[3 t])^4;
disks = Table[p = AngleVector[t];
   center = RotationMatrix[-rot[t]] . p;
   radius = 2 Sin[rot[t]/2];
   Disk[center, radius], {t, Reverse[2. Pi*Subdivide[120]]}];

Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Black], EdgeForm[White], 
  Translate[
     Rotate[Rotate[
       Scale[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -0.0001}, {0, 0, 0.0001}}, #[[2]]], {1, 
         Sqrt[2], 1}], (ArcTan @@ #[[1]]), {0, 0, 1}], 
      Pi/4, {Cos[(ArcTan @@ #[[1]])], Sin[(ArcTan @@ #[[1]])], 
       0}], {Cos[(ArcTan @@ #[[1]])], Sin[(ArcTan @@ #[[1]])], 
      0}] & /@ (disks /. Disk -> List)}, 
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", ViewPoint -> Above, Boxed -> False,
  Background -> Black]





(+1) Neat animation idea, thank you.
